# Is it possible in Mono.Cecil to determine the actual type of an object on which a method is called?

Tags: mono.cecil

For example, consider the following C# code:

```
interface IBase { void f(int); }
interface IDerived : IBase { /* inherits f from IBase */ }

...
void SomeFunction()
{
    IDerived o = ...;
    o.f(5);
}
```

I know how to get a `MethodDefinition` object corresponding to **SomeFunction**.
I can then loop through `MethodDefinition.Instructions`:

```
var methodDef = GetMethodDefinitionOfSomeFunction();
foreach (var instruction in methodDef.Body.Instructions)
{
    switch (instruction.Operand)
    {
        case MethodReference mr:
            ...
            break;
    }
    yield return memberRef;
}
```

And this way I can find out that the method `SomeFunction` calls the function `IBase.f`

Now I would like to know the declared type of the object on which the function `f` is called, i.e. the declared type of `o`.

Inspecting `mr.DeclaringType` does not help, because it returns `IBase`.

This is what I have so far:

```
TypeReference typeRef = null;
if (instruction.OpCode == OpCodes.Callvirt)
{
    // Identify the type of the object on which the call is being made.
    var objInstruction = instruction;
    if (instruction.Previous.OpCode == OpCodes.Tail)
    {
        objInstruction = instruction.Previous;
    }
    for (int i = mr.Parameters.Count; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        objInstruction = objInstruction.Previous;
    }
    if (objInstruction.OpCode == OpCodes.Ldloc_0 ||
        objInstruction.OpCode == OpCodes.Ldloc_1 ||
        objInstruction.OpCode == OpCodes.Ldloc_2 ||
        objInstruction.OpCode == OpCodes.Ldloc_3)
    {
        var localIndex = objInstruction.OpCode.Op2 - OpCodes.Ldloc_0.Op2;
        typeRef = locals[localIndex].VariableType;
    }
    else
    {
        switch (objInstruction.Operand)
        {
            case FieldDefinition fd:
                typeRef = fd.DeclaringType;
                break;
            case VariableDefinition vd:
                typeRef = vd.VariableType;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

where `locals` is `methodDef.Body.Variables`

But this is, of course, not enough, because the arguments to a function can be calls to other functions, like in `f(g("hello"))`. It looks like the case above where I inspect previous instructions must repeat the actions of the virtual machine when it actually executes the code. I do not execute it, of course, but I need to recognize function calls and replace them and their arguments with their respective returns (even if placeholders). It looks like a major pain.

Is there a simpler way? Maybe there is something built-in already?

Comment: I don't know an easy way to achieve this. I guess the "easiest" way to do this is by walking the stack and find where the reference used as the target of the call is pushed (I think you can use some inspiration from https://github.com/lytico/db4o/blob/master/db4o.net/Db4oTool/Db4oTool/Core/StackAnalyzer.cs). 

Anyway, you need to cover a lot of more cases, like,  SomeFunction().f(5). In this case  (if SomeFunction() is typed as IBase) you'll need to find out the actual type returned.

Comment: I know. This is really painful. Hence my question here. Maybe someone did something like this already. By walking the stack do you mean the IL instruction stack? If so - yes, seems so. What a pain...

Comment: @Vagaus - please, arrange your comment as an answer. Although it does not satisfy the question, but it is useful enough to be upvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer of Vagaus helped me come up with a working implementation.

I published it on github - https://github.com/MarkKharitonov/MonoCecilExtensions

Included many unit tests, but I am sure I missed some cases.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of an easy way to achieve this.

The "easiest" way I can think of is to walk the stack and find where the reference used as the target of the call is pushed.

Basically, starting from the call instruction go back one instruction at a time taking into account how each one affects the stack; this way you can find the exact instruction that pushes the reference used as the target of the call (a long time ago I wrote something like that; you can use the code at https://github.com/lytico/db4o/blob/master/db4o.net/Db4oTool/Db4oTool/Core/StackAnalyzer.cs as inspiration).

You'll need also to consider scenarios in which the pushed reference is produced through a method/property; for example, `SomeFunction().f(5)`. In this case you may need to evaluate that method to find out the actual type returned.

Keep in mind that you'll need to handle a lot of different cases; for example, imagine the code bellow:

```
class Utils
{
   public static T Instantiate<T>() where T : new() => new T();
}

class SomeType
{
    public void F(int i) {}
}

class Usage
{
    static void Main()
    {
       var o = Utils.Instantiate<SomeType>();
       o.F(1);
    }
}
```

while walking the stack you'll find that `o` is the target of the method call; then you'll evaluate `Instantiate<T>()` method and will find that it returns `new T()` and knowing that `T` is `SomeType` in this case, that is the type you're looking for.